# Creating a template constrained c++ factory

Tags: c++, c++17, factory, template-meta-programming

I am fairly new to meta programming and I am trying to create a factory singleton that creates cloneable objects.  To this end I have the following code which I have also shared in **[live coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5e94bba24fc6d1fb)**

The thing I am trying to achieve (and it is not included in the code in the coliru link) is to constrain the factory to only allow its `typename T` to `ICloneable` interfaces.

This `ICloneable` interface is defined as follows:

```
template <typename T>
class ICloneable {
public:
    virtual std::unique_ptr<T> clone() const = 0;
};
```

The code to instantiate the factory is shown below.

The closest answer that I can see is [factory of templated class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39792147/factory-of-templated-class).  I was thinking that something along the lines of type traits would be helpful - like `std::is_same_v` - but I have no experience with these meta programming techniques.

```
int main()
{
    auto protoType = std::make_unique<Widget>(1,2);
    const auto gpFactory = Factory<Widget>::getInstance();
    gpFactory->registerType(std::move(protoType), 32u);
    auto cloned = gpFactory->getClone(32u);
    std::cout << *cloned;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For the first error I think you need to remove  `const` here:  `const auto& gFactory = Factory<Widget>::getInstance();` you are modifying `gFactory` with `gFactory.registerType(protoType, 32u)`.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], with all the relevant code _in the question_.

Comment: You should really fix all the unrelated compile errors (e.g. trying to copy a `unique_ptr` instead of moving it) before posting a question. I was going to write an answer, but with that many unrelated errors I can't even work on the problem you want to fix.

Comment: Thanks I just fixed the compilation issues and reworked the question to focus on the meta-programming aspects

Answer (score 3):

The first problem is `gFactory` is a `const&`.  `registerType` is a non-`const` method.

```
auto& gFactory = Factory<Widget>::getInstance();
```

to fix that.

```
gFactory.registerType(protoType, 32u);
```

`registerType` is expecting a `unique_ptr<Widget>`.  You are passing in a `unique_ptr<Widget>`, but you are trying to copy it.

You cannot copy a `unique_ptr`.

```
gFactory.registerType(std::move(protoType), 32u);
```

Next, a missing argument and similar problem here:

```
  const auto& [iter, inserted] = mFactoryRegInfo.try_emplace(rkey, std::move(protoType));
```

and you discard a nodiscard argument in `main`.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1fbd1f71ee2e23bb).

Requiring `ICloneable<T>` is actually considered an anti-pattern in generic code.

```
template<class T, class C=std::unique_ptr<T>>
struct can_clone:std::false_type{};

template<class T>
struct can_clone<T, decltype( std::declval<T const&>().clone() )>:std::true_type {};

template <typename T,
  std::enable_if_t< can_clone<T>{}, bool > = true
>
class Factory final {
public:
    //! Thread safe singleton pattern
    static Factory& getInstance() {
        static std::unique_ptr<Factory> pInstance = std::make_unique<Factory>(token{0});
        return *pInstance;
    }

    //! Registers a new cloneable type in the factory.
    [[nodiscard]] bool registerType(std::unique_ptr<T> protoType, const uint32_t rkey) {
        // Critical Section
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(MutexGuard);
        const auto& [iter, inserted] = mFactoryRegInfo.try_emplace(rkey, std::move(protoType));
        return inserted;
    }

    //! Factory function - returns newly cloned unique_ptr<T>.
    [[nodiscard]] std::unique_ptr<T> getClone(const uint32_t rkey) const {
        // Critical Section
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(MutexGuard);
        const auto& iter = mFactoryRegInfo.find(rkey);
        if (iter != mFactoryRegInfo.end()) {
            return iter->second->clone();
        }
        return nullptr;
    }

    //! C.67: A polymorphic class should suppress copying.
    Factory(const Factory&) = delete;
    Factory(Factory&&) noexcept = delete;
    Factory& operator=(const Factory&) = delete;
    Factory& operator=(Factory&&) noexcept = delete;

    //! Defaulted destructor.
    ~Factory() = default;
private:
    //! Singleton private constructor.
    Factory() = default;
    struct token { explicit token(int){} };
public:
    explicit Factory(token):Factory() {}
private:

    // UUID (uint32_t) to T mapping
    std::map<uint32_t, std::unique_ptr<T>> mFactoryRegInfo{};

    mutable std::mutex MutexGuard;
};
```

this simply requires `T` have a `T::clone() const` method that supports returns `unique_ptr<T>`.

An improvement would be to require that it return a type *convertible to* `unique_ptr<T>`.

Also note I cleaned up your singleton code.  As a note, you shouldn't mix singleton code with functional code; there can be plenty of reasons to have more than one `Factory<Bob>` in the same code base, from unit testing to wanting document-specific object factories.

Singleton, if needed, can be implemented as a separate bit of template metaprogramming.

This will save your life when you realize that singleton lifetime gets insanely more complex when you mix dynamic library loading in.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a0d74050f7a3527a).

Comment: Thanks! I think I was fixing the code in the background after a const hint from @drescherjm - the question has been edited to focus on the real problem of meta programming now

Comment: This doesn't answer the original question though, how to constrain the `Factory` template parameter to types implementing `ICloneable`.

Comment: I agree - that is what I just commented

Comment: @Pezo The question was edited as I was answering it.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont yikes - your second example is a bit of black magic.  I'm running down many rabbit holes trying to understand it.  I'm not sure what the whole token thing is about (looks like a way of using unique ptr for the factory instance), and I am curious as to how to implemented the singleton via meta-programming as you indicated.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont could you explain the line template <typename T, std::enable_if_t <can_clone<T>{}, bool> = true> how does it work - you can edit your answer and I'll accept it if you wish

Comment: @john it permits delegating right to construct to another spot without messing with friendship; yes, for make unique.  The second is a SFINAE technique; it is a substitution failure, or a template non-type parameter of type bool and value true, depending on can clone.

Comment: @john singleton via templates, I'd ask a SO question or search for one.

Comment: You could also replace the `enable_if` with a static assertion to the same effect to improve the error message, now it says `error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::enable_if<false, bool>'` for invalid types.

Comment: @pezo static assert means you cannot in turn SFINAE detect if a type can be passed to Factory.  The error from any SFINAE comes "too late".

Answer (score 3):

You can use a static assertion like this inside `Factory` to make sure `T` implements `ICloneable<T>`:

```
static_assert(std::is_convertible<T*, ICloneable<T>*>::value, "T must implement ICloneable<T>");
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/610dddef1e0debe8)

Note that although there is the `std::is_base_of` trait, `std::is_convertible` is indeed the right type trait to use in this case. To quote [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of#Notes):

> `std::is_base_of<A, B>::value` is true even if `A` is a private, protected, or ambiguous base class of `B`. In many situations, `std::is_convertible<B*, A*>` is the more appropriate test.

Comment: that works thanks, why the pointer semantics in the 'std::is_convertible'?  It also works with 'std::is_convertible<T, ICloneable<T>>::value'

Comment: Because you do polymorphism by pointer or reference. Didn't work for me without the pointer...

Comment: I stand corrected! I missed an error when I removed the pointers

Comment: actually, I think std::is_base_of might be a better choice as it exploits the 'is a' relationship in which case the pointer trick is not necessary.  http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/534fd9a282bf2740

Comment: No it's not, I extended my answer accordingly (at least in the case of your original question). For checking that you passed the right template argument to `ICloneable` I'm not quite sure, it may be more appropriate there.